# Differentiate the Function: $y=e^{k\ tan\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$y=e^{k\tan\sqrt{x}}$

$=e^{k\tan\sqrt{x}}\cdot [{k\tan\sqrt{x}}]'$

$=e^{k\tan\sqrt{x}}\cdot\ (k)\cdot[\tan x^{\frac{1}{2}}]'+(\tan x^{\frac{1}{2}})\cdot[k]'$

$=e^{k\tan\sqrt{x}}\cdot\ (k)\cdot (\frac{1}{2}tanx)\cdot \sec^2x + (\tan x^{\frac{1}{2}})\cdot (1)$

Is my process correct?

Comment: You are missing a par of parens on line 3 and 4.

Comment: $e^{k \tan \sqrt{x}}$ must multiply everything on line $3$, so it is not right.

Comment: If $k$ is a constant, then $k'= 0$..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative solution: $$y = e^{k \tan \sqrt{x}} \implies \ln y = k \tan \sqrt{x},$$so: $$\frac{y'}{y} = \frac{k \sec^2\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x}} \implies y' = e^{k \tan \sqrt{x}}\frac{k \sec^2\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x}}.$$

---

I used the following facts:

- chain rule on $\ln y$ to get $y'/y$ on the left side.
- the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ is $1/(2\sqrt{x})$.
- the derivative of $\tan u$ is $\sec^2 u$.
- the chain rule on $\tan(\sqrt{x})$ along with the two last items.

Comment: Logarithmic differentiation triumphs again!

Comment: Can you show me the formula you used?

Comment: I added some details in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your work is not quite correct.

$$\begin{align}
(e^{k\tan\sqrt x})' &= e^{k\tan\sqrt x}\cdot(k\tan\sqrt x)' \\
 &= e^{k\tan\sqrt x}\cdot k\cdot (\tan\sqrt x)' \\
 &= e^{k\tan\sqrt x}\cdot k\cdot\sec^2\sqrt x\cdot (\sqrt x)' \\
 &= e^{k\tan\sqrt x}\cdot k\cdot\sec^2\sqrt x\cdot \frac 1{2\sqrt x} \\
 &= \frac{k\sec^2\sqrt x\cdot e^{k\tan\sqrt x}}{2\sqrt x}
\end{align}$$

Comment: *Mathematica* yields this answer instantly.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$y=e^{f(g(x))} $then$ \frac{dy}{dx}=e^{f(g(x))}f^{'}(g(x))g^{'}(x)$

In your case.    $ g(x)=\sqrt{x}$
$=>g^{'}(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$

And $ f(x)=tan(\sqrt{x})$
Then $ f^{'}(x)=\sec^2(\sqrt{x})$

Now ,

$\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{k\tan(\sqrt{x})}\sec^2(\sqrt{x})\frac{k}{2\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: Use "'" for derivative, not "1".

Comment: Thank you Marty , I just edited it